# Hard Surface shading artifacts for curved our rounded shapes

Tags: modeling, topology

How would you model this piece of geometry with clean topology/shading like the example below?

[image]

I keep getting strange shading artifacts around the edges and I cant get the seam between the insets sharper without more shading issues:

[image]

Comment: It would be helpful if you added a closeup screenshot of the problem topology to your ask.  Also it can be a good idea to post your blend file, or a truncated version of it that has the problem. The Blender StackExchange has its own service to share blend files: blend-exchange.com/help

Answer (score 1):

You can do it this way:

- Create a circle, cut its half, mirror, extrude:

[image]

- Fill the faces, extrude outwards:

[image]

- Inset these faces, press <kbd>B</kbd> for boundary so that the inset sticks to the mirror:

[image]

- Extrude on Z:

[image]

- Give it an *Array* modifier and a *Simple Deform* modifier (*Bend* mode and 360° on Z):

[image]

- Give it a *Subdivision Surface* modifier:

[image]